# history object with central Routes file

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, history.js

I have seen many examples over the net on how to use history object with React Router. However, I havent stumbled upon a case where the example shows a central routes file as shown below:

**routes.js**

```
const RouteList = () => (
  <main>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
      <Route component={Error} />
    </Switch>
  </main>
);

export default RouteList;
```

**App.js**

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <Header />
           <RouteList />
           <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**history.js**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Can someone shed some light how i can use history with my centralized routes? Or if there is another similar thread please let me know thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom history object need to be provided as a prop to the Router Provider component. In your case you can Specify a Router Provider in `App.js` or `RouteList` depending on whether `Header` and `Footer` also need Router props or not.

```
import browserHistory from './history.js';

...
render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
           <Header />
           <RouteList />
           <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

Also in your `history.js` file, import `createBrowserHistory` like

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
```

Comment: I tried that, it caused my entire application to not render and this error is thrown: `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _history.createBrowserHistory) is not a function`

Comment: Beautiful! At least there is no error thrown now. Can you tell me why a simple re-declaration would stop the error from surfacing?

Comment: createBrowserHistory is not exported as a named export from history module but is a default export in `history/createBrowserHistory`